# how to display an array on view page after running function returning to same page

Tags: php, laravel, highcharts, eloquent, request

i have a page called "grapghhehe" and in that page i have a bar chart and a form for user to select 2 dates(from and to) so when user selects this 2 dates it suppose to show the graph details based on the dates only.. so what i have done where it will return the data which is correct in an array like:

```
array:3 [
  0 => 1
  1 => 17
  2 => 1
]
array:1 [
  0 => 3
]
array:4 [
  0 => 1
  1 => 2
  2 => 1
  3 => 1
]
```

so as you can they are 3 arrays for 3 different values... now i want to return this data on the same page. how can i do that? my code so far:

```html
public function graphheheByDate(Request $request, $companyID)
{
$companyID = $this->decode($companyID);

$match = DiraChatLog::where('status','=','Match')->where('date_access', '>=', $request->from)->where('date_access', '<=', $request->to)
->selectRaw('DATE(date_access) as date, COUNT(1) as cnt') // created_at here is datetime format, only need the date portion using `DATE` function
->orderBy("date")
->groupBy("date")
->get() // return result set (collection) from query builder
->pluck('cnt') // only need the cnt column
->values() // array_values
->sum(); // convert collection to array

$missing = DiraChatLog::where('status','=','Missing')->where('date_access', '>=', $request->from)->where('date_access', '<=', $request->to)
->selectRaw('DATE(date_access) as date, COUNT(1) as cnt') // created_at here is datetime format, only need the date portion using `DATE` function
->orderBy("date")
->groupBy("date")
->get() // return result set (collection) from query builder
->pluck('cnt') // only need the cnt column
->values() // array_values
->sum(); // convert collection to array

$noAnswer = DiraChatLog::where('status','=','No Answer')->where('date_access', '>=', $request->from)->where('date_access', '<=', $request->to)
->selectRaw('DATE(date_access) as date, COUNT(1) as cnt') // created_at here is datetime format, only need the date portion using `DATE` function
->orderBy("date")
->groupBy("date")
->get() // return result set (collection) from query builder
->pluck('cnt') // only need the cnt column
->values() // array_values
->sum(); // convert collection to array

$match = array(0 => $match);
$missing = array(0 => $missing);
$noAnswer = array(0 => $noAnswer);
// dd($match,$missing,$noAnswer);

$from = $request->from;
$to = $request->to;
// dd($from, $to);

$companyID = $this->encodeID($companyID);

return view('AltHr.Chatbot.graphhehe', compact('companyID','from','to'))->with('match',json_encode($match,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK))->with('missing',json_encode($missing,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK))->with('noAnswer',json_encode($noAnswer,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));     
}
```

in this function when i dd the 3 values are correct details. i only want this data to bring to the same page to change the graph.

my graph javascript is as below:

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var match = <?php echo $match; ?>;
  var missing = <?php echo $missing; ?>;
  var noAnswer = <?php echo $noAnswer; ?>;

  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Unique Visitors'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Dates'
        ],
        crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total'
        }
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
      enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span>{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y}</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Match',
        data: [match]

    }, {
        name: 'Missing',
        data: [missing]

    }, {
        name: 'No Answer',
        data: [noAnswer]

    }]
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can use `with()` to return the data. Or `compact()` to return to the view.

Comment: @Jonjie yeah i already did that in my code. but i want to know how to display the values in the same view page

Comment: Try `{{ print_r($variable) }}`.

Comment: If that worked. I'll try to explain it to the answer below.